# video.js loop not looping - stopping on last frame

Tags: video.js

Attempting to get a basic short video looping but can't get it to work.

This is the code I'm attempting to use:

```
    <video class="bg1" preload loop autoplay>
        <source src="video/bg1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try setting up a jsfiddle or posting all of your code.  

Is this meant to be an HTML5 video question and not a video.js question?

Comment: Hi - this is a video.js question. I am using it as I needed 2 video elements playing in the browser and using the default video element only allows 1. video.js lets me play 2 video but is not looping as outlined in the options section here - https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/options.md

Comment: Do you have the data-setup needed for video.js? Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qV8eL/  I copied the code straight from videojs.com and added "loop" to the video tag.  Note the "data-setup={}" which is needed for video.js to initialize

Comment: Thanks for the comments b.kelley - found the fix for my case, answered it below.

Answer (score 0):

Found what the issue was in my case. I am using WebStorm and was viewing the site in debug mode - when opening the site, either local or on my web server the video loops as it should.